# Drop 12v down to 6V

Tags: resistors, voltage

I want to power 3 x 12v 0.2A PC fans from the Molex power supply on my PC PSU, the only issue is that I don't want them to run at full speed.

So I am trying to half the voltage to 6v.

I have built this, and with no load it reads 6v across R2 however when I plug the fans in it reads approx 1.5v and my bench PSU reads no current draw.

What am i missing?

[image]

Comment: Use a DC-DC Converter Module (i.e. Buck Converter or Step-Down Converter). There are hundreds of converter modules with adjustable output.

Comment: @Justme yeah, thanks, basically the answer is don't do what I'm doing. :)

Comment: Yes, resistive divider is not suitable for powering items. What you could do is measure current consumption at 6V, and calculate a series resistance value to drop 6V at that current. The fan might have trouble starting up reliably. That's the reason dedicated fan controllers exist.

Comment: Yeah I was just trying to be quick and dirty about it until I can buy one. But I figured out a different solution, molex also has a 5v pin so I just moved the fan hub input to power from the 5v line instead.

Comment: Look at your resistor values. What is the maximum possible current you could get through 10k on a 12 V supply? How does that match up with your fan's requirements? Anyway, it's not the way to regulate voltage to the fan.